# getting error on php database query

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know much about php. this is a php  i'm using to send data form android. but while testing, i'm using it from a html. from this html i send iddevice, latitud and longitud variables.

as you can see in the php code, first i get the name related to the iddevice sent from the html from the DB.

the problem is I'm not getting the name variable from the database. the name should be "manuel", but on my mysql DB i'm getting "Resource id #2" instead. the other variables are correct in database row (iddevice, latitud and longitud).

any idea on why is this happening? thx in advance

php code:

```
<?php

// conexion a la base de datos
mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("qry899");

// conseguimos el nombre
$newname = mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='".$_POST["iddevice"]."'") or die(mysql_error());

// insertamos id de registro devuelto por el GCM
mysql_query("INSERT INTO position (iddevice, nombre, latitud, longitud) VALUES ('".$_POST["iddevice"]."', '$newname', '".$_POST["latitud"]."', '".$_POST["longitud"]."')") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: `$newname` will hold the resource after the query is executed, you need to fetch the data, check mysql_fetch_* functions manual how to fetch data.

Comment: public website - use your common sense and don't post database login details...

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) and using an [obsolete API](http://bit.ly/phpmsql).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ (though given you already posted your database credentials and they're still in the edit history I think that might be the least of your problems)

Comment: Downvotters Please give a reason for -1.

Comment: We need to come up with a 'cut-n-paste' comment about SQL injections and `mysql_` functions being deprectaed @JohnConde

Comment: @imsiso downvoters are not required to give comments for any number of reasons.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have a few that I use depending on the context.

Comment: I already have one (more than one actually) lol @JayBlanchard (just as John does) ;-) (typing them over and over isn't our cup 'o tea lol) see below...

Comment: Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - you know I said please and didn't say or I will KILL YOU and you know the reason will still help me to improve my question or understand and correct my mistake for next time.Any way thanks for your respond.(-:

Comment: But it isn't your question @imsiso, unless you changed identities from the question above to your answer below? The OP might have gotten DV's for using `mysql_` or for leaving the code open to SQL injection attacks or for including login information. *shrug*

Comment: @JayBlanchard - OK Sorry My English is not so good. You are right this is not my question. But This is what just happens on my questions too (down vote without reason). So what would happen if you let me know my mistakes. Maybe I will not make myself and others bother?

Comment: Rather than ask for DV reasons just ask how you can improve your question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - that's what I do every time I got down vote. But also I myself will not wait for the OP to ask me . I will put something like `-1 please try too ...` or `please try to ...`. But still you can do as you wish. thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually extracting the value from the database, you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`:

```
// conseguimos el nombre
$result = mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='".$_POST["iddevice"]."'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$newname = $row['nombre'];
```

And you should avoid mysql* functions, as mentioned by others.

Lastly change your database login details, they are in the edit history so anyone can access it

Comment: *"Lastly change your database login details, they are in the edit history so anyone can access it"* --- Exactly. Yet, if anything and in order for that to not become accessible by others, the question would need to be deleted altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc($res)` to get a row like:

**+** Please avoid using **mysql_** . Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
<?php

// conexion a la base de datos
mysql_connect("xxx", "yyyy", "zzz") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("ccc");

// conseguimos el nombre
$res1= mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='".$_POST["iddevice"]."'") or die(mysql_error());//this will return a resource pointer

$record=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);//this will return a record of pointed select the(res1)
$newname = $record['nombre'];// this will give you the specific field you were looking for 

// insertamos id de registro devuelto por el GCM
mysql_query("INSERT INTO position (iddevice, nombre, latitud, longitud) VALUES ('".$_POST["iddevice"]."', '$newname', '".$_POST["latitud"]."', '".$_POST["longitud"]."')") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: loop through the values will help. while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
  echo $row["nombre"];
}

Comment: *"Please avoid using mysql_ . Use mysqli or PDO"* --- Actually, without using prepared statements, both can still be open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - yes But you know with links I had provided the reader will understand the benefits and the reason of using PDO or mysqli and also I am sure in that links there are somethings about SQL injection.

Comment: *Hm...* I'm not about to go through pages and pages of code to "hopefully" find something closely related to what you just said. The best thing to do is to simply mention the term "prepared statements", and the OP can Google it.

Comment: +1 - Thanks that's what I will do after this. I didn't know the keyword "prepared statements"

Comment: You're welcome. Here, save these two links in a text file, and/or add it to your answer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// conexion a la base de datos
mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("qry899");

// conseguimos el nombre
$newname = mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='".$_POST["iddevice"]."'") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($newname);
$newname1 = $row['latitud'];

// insertamos id de registro devuelto por el GCM
mysql_query("INSERT INTO position (iddevice, nombre, latitud, longitud) VALUES ('".$_POST["iddevice"]."', '$newname1', '".$_POST["latitud"]."', '".$_POST["longitud"]."')") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will never work as long as u do it like this `mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='".$_POST["iddevice"]."'")` try first to assign `$_POST["iddevice"]` to a variable and after use that variable in the query, something like this:

```
$device = $_POST["iddevice"];
mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM gcm_v3 WHERE iddevice='$device'");
```